# How to unassign dupe skill point?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

The first time I used the Oxygen-not included skills system I accidentally assigned a skill point at the wrong place.
How can that be undone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to build the Skill Scrubber machine, and shake the duplicant until its skills reset.

The [Skill Scrubber](https://oni-db.com/details/resetskillsstation) is listed under Stations.

Comment: Just to confirm; this won't lose me any skill points, right? I'll be able to re-assign them right away.

Comment: It's my understanding that the duplicant keeps their points, but the assignment is reset.